# can't import mysql in node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, backend

I didn't expect that I'll stuck with this simple (at first glance) question, but I really haven't find anything helpful about the problem. I use the following code in my connect.js file:

```
`let mysql = require('mysql');

let connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'xxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    database: 'xxxxx'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('error: ' + err.message);
    }

    console.log('Connected to the MySQL server.');
});
```

`
then I run the following command, and recieve this response:

`    $ node connect.js
file:///home/timothy/Desktop/Backend/connect.js:1
let mysql = require('mysql');
^

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at file:///home/timothy/Desktop/Backend/connect.js:1:13
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:145:37)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:182:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)`
```

I tried to remove 'type': 'module' from my package.json file, then it works as intended, I recieve console.error (but that is not the point, it's related to my database). But if I remove 'type': 'module' my main file index.js doesn't work, because it uses express js dependency. So now I wondering how to make both files work properly. I tried to install requirejs via

```
`$ npm i requirejs
```

`
but it doesn't solve my problem

UPDATE:
mysql npm package is installed of course

and I see the same problem here:
[How can I get all the filesnames from a directory on the server in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75266905/how-can-i-get-all-the-filesnames-from-a-directory-on-the-server-in-javascript)

Many people says that this error happens when you try running code in a browser and not in a nodejs server. I don't know if I have to specify that this file is for node server. I just run

```
node filename.js
```

As you can see, may be I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to change to this

```
import * as mysql from 'mysql'
```

or

```
import mysql from 'mysql'
```

And set `type` to `module`

Answer (score 0):

I think your mysql npm package is not installed or an unwanted  character put before
`let mysql = require('mysql');` line, so at first run `npm i mysql` command on your project directory. then use the following code...

```
let mysql = require('mysql');

let connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'localhost',
user: 'root',
password: '',
database: 'ecomm'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
  return console.error('error: ' + err.message);
 }

console.log('Connected to the MySQL server.');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, I forgot to mention, I already installed mysql via npm, If you have some another ideas about that, it would be great.